Remove rows of one pandas df using another df, but enable "wildcard" behavior when second df is missing values
I have a df of hundreds of thousands of rows, which can contain errors. A team is manually reviewing/identifying, and I'm trying to enable flexible removal of combinations to purge.
There are three key values, and my hope was to enable any of these values to be populated, depending on the removal scope. I want to remove rows matching the broadest definition, treating empty columns per row as if they are wildcards.
Here is a repro of one approach, but I'm wondering if there's a more vectorized/elegant method someone will suggest?
import pandas as pd

target_df = pd.DataFrame({'id_1': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '4', '4'],
                          'id_2': ['2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '5', '5'],
                          'attr': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D']})
remove_df = pd.DataFrame({'id_1': ['1', '1', '4'],
                          'id_2': ['2', '3', None],
                          'attr': ['A', None, None]})

result_df = target_df.copy()
for _, row in remove_df.iterrows():
    row = row.loc[row.notna()]
    row = row.to_frame().T.reset_index(drop=True)
    filter_cols = row.columns
    mask = result_df[filter_cols].eq(row.values).all(axis=1)
    result_df = result_df[~mask]

result_df

  id_1 id_2 attr
1    1    2    B
4    2    3    C

Some other thoughts:

One thought is to "chunk" these, applying the mask per unique combination of non-NA values in remove_df? That also seems tedious to handle, as there are 7 permutations of possible NA/non-NA columns.

figuring out which rows to remove based on merge() is intriguing. I think this would require scanning target_df to expand remove_df with all possible values when its value is None. That, or we're back to the many logic branches and we merge using on=[cols], once per combination of non-NA columns.

I could build tuples of non-NA column combos ahead of time, then iterate through those? Then I'm doing this at most 7 times vs. one per row.


There probably won't be that many of these removals (guessing hundreds), so if the above is pythonic enough, I'll let it be.
I'm mainly asking as I didn't see this exact question, and it's an interesting exercise. I'm intermediate in python skill, so I'd love to see how others would approach this.

Related:

this question is close, asking how to merge while ignoring NaN: Pandas merging on multi columns while ignoring NaN
similar idea, merging n times, then concatenating results: How to merge two data frames while excluding the NaN value column?
credit for the mask approach above: pandas isin comparison to multiple columns, not including index
very similar to my initial thought, but didn't love filling in all the permutations: How to merge with wildcard? - Pandas


off of first glance, I would avoid using iterrows() especially if you have 100,000+ rows

Thanks @iBeMeltin; for clarification, the target df has 100k rows, but I think there will be ~hundreds to remove (and thus iterate through).

also, I am kind of confused by your logic. what is the criteria to remove rows? is result_df your expected output?

@iBeMeltin result_df is the desired output, yeah. I edited it in for reference. The idea is to select rows from target_df that don't have an equivalent in remove_df, when considering a null as a wildcard.

@iBeMeltin sorry for the confusion. I could have operated on target_df directly, but wanted the code to preserve it. Ultimately, I'd summarize the aim: "if there's a match on non-null column values in remove_df with target_df, remove the applicable rows from target_df."

With only a few hundred removals, performance shouldn't be too bad, using the rule of thumb from cs95's answer here: 'You should not use any function with "iter" in its name for more than a few thousand rows or you will have to get used to a lot of waiting.'
That said, there are still a few improvements you could make:

Instead of filtering result_df1 multiple times (making a copy each time), build up mask. I'm using a reduction of binary OR.
Use .eq(<Series>, axis=1) instead of having to finagle with a dataframe

from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

def _f(row):
    row_valid = row[row.notna()]
    return target_df[row_valid.index].eq(row_valid, axis=1).all(axis=1)

mask = reduce(or_, (_f(row) for _, row in remove_df.iterrows()))

result_df1 = target_df[~mask]
result_df1

  id_1 id_2 attr
1    1    2    B
4    2    3    C


I have made a couple of changes to your approach, and also simulated a larger dataframe to perform time measurements. On your code, I get around 2.15seconds, and on the below, around 1.20 seconds.
Mask Creation:

Your code creates a boolean mask for each row in remove_df and
applies it sequentially.
the code below creates a single, combined boolean
mask that incorporates all the filtering criteria from remove_df.

Filtering Application:

Your code filters the DataFrame repeatedly in each iteration.
The code below applies the mask once to filter the DataFrame in a single
operation.

import pandas as pd
import time

def filter_df_pandas(target_df, remove_df):
    """
    Filters target_df based on criteria specified in remove_df.

    Args:
        target_df: The DataFrame to be filtered.
        remove_df: The DataFrame containing the filter criteria.

    Returns:
        Filtered df.
    """
    mask = pd.Series(True, index=target_df.index)  # Initialize a boolean mask
    for row in remove_df.itertuples(index=False):
        row_mask = pd.Series(True, index=target_df.index)
        for col in remove_df.columns:
            if pd.notna(getattr(row, col)):
                row_mask &= target_df[col] == getattr(row, col)
        mask &= ~row_mask
    return target_df[mask]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Duplicate data in target_df by a million
    target_df = pd.concat([target_df] * 1_000_000, ignore_index=True)

    start_time = time.time()
    result_df = filter_df_pandas(target_df, remove_df)
    end_time = time.time()

    print(result_df)
    print(f"Filtering took: {end_time - start_time:.2f} seconds")


Hey, I had the same idea for the mask :) I did mask = pd.Series(False, index=target_df.index) then I realized you can do a reduction instead, to make it even cleaner :)
